# Github Search API for searching code using a repository name

Tags: github, github-api

I am using Github search APIs of enterprise version (https://{{GitBaseInternalURL}}/api/v3) in my code.

I am able to search the code using the endpoint below:

```
"code_search_url": "https://{{GitBaseInternalURL}}/api/v3/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}"
```

However ***I want to search the code based on the given repository name***.
I have searched a lot of content online and I could not find any suitable endpoint for my use case.
Can anybody help me find the right endpoint for my purpose?